# How to resolve Detected package downgrade warnings

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2017

I've been hitting my head against a brick wall with a very annoying problem. If anyone has any ideas that would be great! I'm in visual studio 2017 with a .net core 1.1 asp.net website. I'm using ravendb. The problem is that I'm getting 4 build warnings which cause the deployment to azure to fail. The warnings are:

> Warning       Detected package downgrade: RavenDB.Client from 3.5.35130-Unstable to 3.5.4-patch-35202 
>    ApiHubNunitTests (>= 1.0.0) -> ApiHub (>= 1.0.0) -> RavenDB.DependencyInjection (>= 1.0.0) -> RavenDB.Client (>= 3.5.35130-Unstable) 
>    ApiHubNunitTests (>= 1.0.0) -> ApiHub (>= 1.0.0) -> RavenDB.Client (>= 3.5.4-patch-35202)
>
> Warning       Detected package downgrade: RavenDB.Client from 3.5.35130-Unstable to 3.5.4-patch-35202 
>    ApiHub (>= 1.0.0) -> RavenDB.DependencyInjection (>= 1.0.0) -> RavenDB.Client (>= 3.5.35130-Unstable) 
>    ApiHub (>= 1.0.0) -> RavenDB.Client (>= 3.5.4-patch-35202)
>
> Warning   MSB3277 Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly that could not be resolved.  These reference conflicts are listed in the build log when log verbosity is set to detailed. BlueSkyApiHub   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets  1964
>
> Warning   MSB3277 Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly that could not be resolved.  These reference conflicts are listed in the build log when log verbosity is set to detailed. ApiHubNunitTests    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets  1964    Build

I've turned on the detailed build output and found this:

> There was a conflict between "System.Net.Primitives, Version=4.0.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" and "System.Net.Primitives, Version=4.0.11.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".

and this

> There was a conflict between "Raven.Client.Lightweight, Version=3.5.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" and "Raven.Client.Lightweight, Version=3.5.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null".

and this

> There was a conflict between "Raven.Client.UniqueConstraints, Version=3.5.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" and "Raven.Client.UniqueConstraints, Version=3.5.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null".

There are a few more all related to ravendb.

I'm not sure where to go now? Any ideas?

EDIT: Here are the .csproj files for both projects

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
    <PackageTargetFallback>portable-net45+win8</PackageTargetFallback>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="wwwroot\" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="BCrypt.Net-Core" Version="1.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Flurl.Http" Version="1.2.0-pre" />
    <PackageReference Include="Maqduni.AspNetCore.Identity.RavenDb" Version="1.3.34" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" Version="2.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="1.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="2.0.0-preview2-final" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="10.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="NodaTime" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="RavenDB.Client" Version="3.5.4-patch-35202" />
    <PackageReference Include="RavenDB.Client.UniqueConstraints" Version="3.5.4-patch-35202" />
    <PackageReference Include="RavenDB.DependencyInjection" Version="1.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" Version="5.1.4" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="1.0.0-msbuild3-final" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Update="appsettings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

and for the other project:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="CompareNETObjects" Version="3.9.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="FakeItEasy" Version="4.0.0-beta001" />
    <PackageReference Include="Flurl.Http" Version="1.2.0-pre" />
    <PackageReference Include="MyTested.AspNetCore.Mvc.Universe" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="10.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="NodaTime" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit" Version="3.7.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\BlueSkyApiHub\BlueSkyApiHub.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: Can you share your [.csproj file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/project-json-to-csproj).

Comment: Just added them

Comment: Have no PackageReference related information?

Comment: No that's it.I've narrowed it down to what I think is the issue. RavenDb references an old version of System.Net.Primitives. Due to a spec change, I no longer need a data store so have got rid of Raven now. No more conflict.

Answer (score 1):

I did a fair amount of googling on this one and i tried adding various commands on the csproj file but nothing worked for me. ***I was upgrading my packages to .net core 2.0*** and then i ran into package downgrade errors.

**In the end i did the following:**

1. Took a copy of my csproj to note down the exact packages and versions i was using.
2. Removed all packages from the original cs proj file.
3. Saved and confimed in side VS all of the build errors for missing packages,
4. Confirmed that the packages had been dereferenced too from the references list.
5. I manually started re-adding aspnetcore packages one by one.

Comment: Sorry did not realise at the time - i was working with .netcore. I have used the same process above also when working regular asp.net projects.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the Nuget packages with higher versions from the nuget cache on your computer. For me the Nuget cache is located in $HOMEPATH/.nuget/packages.